# Erro no Gradle Sync ao compilar projeto

Tags: android-studio, app, gradle

Estou terminando um projeto no Android Studio, e atualizei para a versao 2.1, dai começou a me aparecer erros, uns ja resolvi, esse me persegue; Ao sincronizar o gradle me aparece estas mensagens:
[image: erro1]

Aqui esta as configuraçoes do meu Gradle:

[image: erro2]

[image: erro3]

e abaixo esta meu pacote SDK:
[image: ERRO4]

Comment: mude o seu buildToolsVersion para '23.0.3' e perceba que no seu pacote de suporte em -> compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23..0-alpha1' existe um erro, tente corrigir assim: compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0-alpha1' e faça um novo sync e depois do sync, um build.

Comment: :appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
support:support-v4:23.3.0'
support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'  Corrigiu meu problema.. agora estou com problema Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 8.3.0.